# ActiveRecord: milliseconds aren't taken into account when using a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, milliseconds

I'm working on a project with a rails api and an iOS client, using the updated_at field as the reference to detect modifications on the server that happened after the last pull from the client.

The updated_at datetime has a precision in milliseconds, meaning that

```
Model.updated_at.to_f
```

returns something like "1368977381.063427".
This is sent to the client formatted as "2013-05-19T15:29:41.063427000Z".

The trouble is, when I get that datetime back from the client, parse it and query with it, the milliseconds are lost.

```
last_update = DateTime.strptime("2013-05-19T15:29:41.063427000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%z")
Model.where("updated_at > ?", last_update)
```

is as good as doing

```
last_update = DateTime.strptime("2013-05-19T15:29:41Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
Model.where("updated_at > ?", last_update)
```

As a result, I always get at least one result when I should get none, because the milliseconds are truncated.

How can I take those into account in my query ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Model.where("updated_at > ?", last_update.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%z"))
```

You can also set this format as the standard format for DateTime in databases by setting (i.e. in an initiallizer):

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db]= '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%z'
```

then your original query works again:

```
Model.where("updated_at > ?", last_update)
```

See the [Rails API](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/to_formatted_s) for `DateTime.to_s` (aka .to_formated_s)

Comment: My problem was that the precision of the timestamp stored in the database was to 5 decimal places, whereas my client was storing the timestamp to 3 decimal places... when performing a greater than query, it would always return that same record because of the extra 2 decimal places.

Comment: I'm surprised there is not a more native way to support milliseconds in Rails. :-/

Comment: The comment linking to the Rails API was the most helpful, since it helps you figure out what to change in your code to get the "standard logic" up and running

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the ISO8601 standard you can use `.iso8601(10)`.  Don't know why but it rounds to seconds by default.