# Rails ignoring miliseconds when compare date inside "order"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having a trouble that I can't solve by myself, hope you can help me.

## The problem

Currently I'm trying to get the Posts that user doesn't read yet, in other words, I want the posts that attends to `posts.updated_at > viewed_posts.last_viewed_at`. The date was been inserted right in the database, the problem is with the my ActiveRecord query.

**Following is my query:**

```
posts.joins(:viewed_posts).where(viewed_posts: 
    { person_id: current_user.id, person_type: current_user.class.name})
    .order('posts.updated_at > viewed_posts.last_viewed_at DESC')
```

But this doesn't work very well, appears that ActiveRecord ignores miliseconds, what change dramatically my result.

I have one post `updated_at 2014-02-24 21:38:30.466789` and the same post was `last_viewed_at 2014-02-24 21:38:30.497867` by one user. As you can see, this user already saw the post miliseconds later, and we can imagine that user don't will see this post, according to my query - but surprise! This post appears as one result of the query!

I can only imagine that ActiveRecord is ignoring miliseconds, or have another possible cause?

## Possible solution

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800939/activerecord-milliseconds-are-lost-when-using-a-where-clause), but this doesn't helped me because `order` don't accept two arguments (and I don't know how I can include this code in my `where` clause).

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: What actual SQL is getting run? Get it from Rails's log, or get it from the PostgreSQL server error logs after enabling `log_statement = 'all'`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `posts.updated_at > viewed_posts.last_viewed_at` be in your WHERE clause rather than ORDER BY?

Comment: @CraigRinger I will update the question soon, thanks for your reply

Comment: @muistooshort I think yes, but...how can I do that with my architecture? I already tried by many ways put this sentence in "Where", but this always give me an error. Can you post an working "where" clause with this sentence?

Comment: What attempts have you made and what are the errors you get? What do the `posts` and `viewed_posts` tables look like?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying `posts.joins("RIGHT JOIN viewed_posts ON posts.id = viewed_posts.post_id").where('viewed_posts.person_id = ? AND viewed_posts.person_type = ? AND posts.updated_at > viewed_posts.last_viewed_at', u.id, u.class.name)` , but this isn't working. This query must return all posts that user don't see any time too. I'm testing this and some variants with friends and this always returns empty. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Tried Left Join too: `h.posts.joins("LEFT JOIN viewed_posts ON posts.id = viewed_posts.post_id").where('viewed_posts.person_id = ? AND viewed_posts.person_type = ? AND posts.updated_at > viewed_posts.last_viewed_at', u.id, u.class.name)`. Both return empty, but I have lot of posts that I never read, and when I go to page this isn't showed (of course, because query returns empty).

Comment: So... the real SQL, not the Rails query language, is .... ?